# PHP unset() SESSION data always executed before echo

Tags: php, session

Lets say i have this code:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>

        <div class="CustomErrorMessage">
            <img src="" /><?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?>
        </div>

<?php
unset($_SESSION['message']);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

This produces:
1. empty Session array var dump
2. the div
3. a warning, that this index is not found
4. another empty var dump for the session array

Lets say i add die() to line 2 here. Then this happens:
The SESSION array is var_dumped and the message IS there!

How is this possible? It looks like the unset() is executed BEFORE the echo always.

My goal with this is just to show an error message to the user which is transported from page to page via $_SESSION and not shown more than once (so if it was shown, delete it).

This sounds like an intern PHP Problem to me?

Thanks!

Comment: probably you're reloading the page, so the message is there ONCE, then it gets unset. you reload the page, and it's no longer there, so you get your errors.

Comment: @MarcB: Good idea, but the part where i execute this, is at the very bottom of the root page, nothing after this is execute other than closing the body and html tag... There is no header() executed or any kind of redirect

Comment: well, php doesn't timetravel. the unset() cannot possibly execute before the vardump/div output.

Comment: @MarcB: There needs to be a reason for this...

Comment: yes, but it's probably your code (elsewhere/not shown) causing it. like I said. php doesn't time travel. a variable/value doesn't just vanish in the space of 5 lines of code.

Comment: @MarcB: I just checked with the Chrome Network Tab AND added a counter to see if it increases by 1 or by 2 (because of reloads). There are NO reloads, nothing!